# How to use Universal-Image-Loader in Service?

Tags: android, android-service, universal-image-loader, illegalstateexception

I am making an image Notification.

I use GCM to push. And by GCM, I send an image URI.

When Service in android app got URI, by Universal-Image-Loader, I try to load image at the URI.

But in this case, I got an error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader.displayImage(...) must be invoked from the main thread or from Looper thread
```

This is my code at Service below :

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    ImageLoader imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    //ImageLoader.getInstance().destroy();
    imageloader.init(config);

    imageloader.loadImage(img_url, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            notificationWithBigPicture(GcmIntentService.this, PUSH_TITLE, PUSH_CONTENT, R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm, loadedImage, GcmMain.class);
        }
    }); 


public void notificationWithBigPicture(Context context, String title, String message, int icon, Bitmap banner, Class<?> activityClass) {
    Log.i(TAG,"6666");

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, activityClass);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(icon)
    .setTicker(title)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(message)
    .setAutoCancel(true);

    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle style = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    //style.setBigContentTitle(title);
    //style.setSummaryText(message);
    style.bigPicture(banner);

    builder.setStyle(style);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
    builder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    Log.v("9999","");
}
```

But when code flow goes into the method public void onLoading Complete (),
App is gone and show that error.

What is the problem?

Comment: Maybe `loadImageSync(...)` is more suitable for you?

Comment: Thank you! I solve this problem exactly by you, Nostras. I know you made this!

Answer (score 1):

Until version 1.9.1 the method loadImage() required to be called in the main thread. 
From version 1.9.2 and later, this requirements is expired. You can call loadImage() wherever.